# Can not connect Socket.io from client Android

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io, connection, parameter-passing

**What is my goal:**

I want to connect to a socket configured with socket.io on a namespace with one connection parameter from Android. For example I want to connect to https://www.socket.com/messages/ with a parameter "token" and value "1234567890abc".

**What I know so far:**

The socket fully works on the web client and on the IOS client. The IOS client uses the following code:

```
self.socketClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: APIManager.sharedManager.baseURL)!, options: [.Log(true), .Path(chat), .ConnectParams(["token":token])])
self.turnOnAllInitialListeners()
self.socket.connect()
```

Nothing fancy as you can see. This are the values :

```
[0] : log
    - Log : false
▿ [1] : path
     - Path : "/server-x/"
▿ [2] : secure
     - Secure : true
▿ [3] : connectParams
     ▿ ConnectParams : 1 elements
          ▿ [0] : 2 elements
                - .0 : "token"
                - .1 : bXByAFX7vYMERLyOBIgbP50ufPMOPKv
```

This connection is succesfull and I've been trying to achieve the same in Android with this approach:

```
    String url = "https://demo.test.test.nl";
    IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
    opts.query = "token=bXByAFX7vYMERLyOBIgbP50ufPMOPKv";
// Tried on and off
//        opts.path = "/server-x";
    try {
        opts.sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Manager manager = new Manager(new URI(url), opts);
        // Tried on and off
        mSocket = manager.socket("/server-x");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not connect to socket server");
    }
    setConnectionListeners();
    setChatListeners();
    // Connected always returns into false.
    mSocket.connect();
```

There is nothing wrong with the namespace, the path or the token. Also tried without the SSL part and with and without separate manager. Also the code doesn't end up in one of the catches. What could go wrong? All help is appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was in the hostname/ssl certificate. After turning on the logging I saw that the problem was a transport error. And I found the most nasty fix, that fixes it for now and doesn't let me doubt about my socket code.

```
    private SSLContext temporarySslSolution() {
    SSLContext sc = null;
    try {
        sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new RelaxedHostNameVerifier());
    return sc;

}

public static class RelaxedHostNameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
}

public TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
    }
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                   String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                   String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }
} };
```